# If the administrator removes the Chrome extensions, it is removed from all users?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If the administrator removes the Chrome extensions, it is removed from all users?

If the Google removes the Chrome extensions, it is removed from all users?

About other Stories (Firefox, Opera, Safari ...) that we know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no-one is signed in, yes.
Otherwise, it is based on what accounts are synced with the extensions.

*i.e.* if an account is synced with an extension, the extension will be available when that google account is signed in to chrome.